# Job to process a cube is failing but manual process succeeding

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

We have an sql server job with xmla code that processes the cube fully, the job is divided into many steps where first the dimensions get processed and then the cube. The dimensions' process succeeds but when reaching to processing the cube measure group it is failing with this memory error:

> "Error ErrorCode="3238002695" Description="Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" / Error ErrorCode="3239837701" Description="Server: The operation has been cancelled because there is not enough memory available for the application. If using a 32-bit version of the product, consider upgrading to the 64-bit version or increasing the amount of memory available on the machine."
>   (the product is already 64 bit)

Then when going to the cube directly and manually processing the measure group, it succeeds.

Does anyone have any input or feedback regarding this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the XMLA that fails? Can you manually process the cube but instead of clicking OK to start it click Script and include that XMLA which succeeds? Is this multidimensional or tabular? How much available memory does Task Manager show? How much memory is msmdsrv.exe consuming now and while processing?

Comment: Additional questions: what show MSAS11:Memory counters in Performance Monitor? Is there the same setting for parallel processing in manual/auto executions (<Parallel MaxParallel="..."> in XMLA)?